# How to create a union of two shapes in CSS and apply dropshadow to the final shape?

Tags: html, css

I am mainly a designer, but I am making a mock HTML document using some basic HTML and CSS to demonstrate the realizability of my design. Below is the custom shape I have designed on Figma.

[image: My design on Figma]

Now, I am barely familiar with HTML or CSS, but by doing some rudimentary Googling I was able to create the shape i wanted in CSS. Below are the code snippets of the HTML and CSS I have used to realize the result seen in the image below the code.

```
/* Html Part */
<body>
    <div id="topLabel">
        <div id="topLabelRectangle"></div>
        <div id="topLabelCircle"></div>
    </div>
</body>

/*CSS Part*/
#topLabelRectangle {
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
top: 0%;
bottom: 90%;

background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 50px;
//box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.25);
}

#topLabelCircle {
position: absolute;
left: 47%;
right: 47%;
top: 4.5%;
bottom: 83%;
background: #FFFFFF;

//box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.25);
border-radius: 250px;
}
```

The result I got from the code above (without the dropshadow property)

[image: The result I got from the code above (without the dropshadow property)]

Now, when I tried adding the shadow property, it looked as shown below (which is not the expected result I was expecting)

Result I obtained with shadows applied separately

[image: Result I obtained with shadows applied separately]

In order to tackle this I tried the following

1. I removed the shadow property from the individual elements.
2. Added the property to the parent of both the elements as shown below

```
   #topLabel {
       box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.25);
   }
```

When I did so, the shadow property wasn't applied to any element and looked like the one before shadow was added.

I presume, my lack of knowledge on the subject matter is the reason behind my incapability to find a solution for this using Google. Please, guide me in the matter.

Comment: Umm.. is it Okay to answer my own question? Idk! Anyhow, I felt like a complete moron not to have attempted this as a person who regularly works on layers. I achieved the result by changing the shape properties of the circle as shown below.

#topLabelCircle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 46.2%;
    right: 46.2%;
    top: 7.5%;
    bottom: 84%;
    background: #FFFFFF;

    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.25);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 300px 300px;
}

however, i am still keeping the question as my solution was sort of a jugaad and i would like to know better.

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem. cant you just put two images say this is what I want and this is what I have. I read this text 3 times could not figure out what is the problem

Comment: @SrivathsaBN Yes, if you solved your issue, please post an answer. Stack Overflow tries to build a collection of common questions and answers and by posting your solution as an answer post, you contribute to that :) It's also easier to format and highlight things there. Note that you can only accept your own answer after a few days after your question was posted (I think two). Welcome to SO!

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Hi, thank you. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

So, I found a solution to my problem by just changing my circle in to a semi circle and placing it exactly at the edge of my rectangle. Semi circle was created by varying the border radius property as shown below,

```
#topLabelRectangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 92.5%;

  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.25);
}

#topLabelCircle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 46.2%;
  right: 46.2%;
  top: 7.5%;
  bottom: 84%;
  background: #FFFFFF;

  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.25);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 300px 300px;
}
```

Here, is the result I obtained:
[image: Solution Result]

But still what I did was some kind of designer jugaad, but I would like to know if there is a technical possibility to get the same result.